# Adding at the end of a linked list and displaying the first value in the linked list?

Tags: c++

Im making a Queue singly linked list for an assignment.  My insert method should add the value at the end of the linked list.  My first() method should return the value of the first node in the linked list.  Here is my attempt at this:

```
void QueueList::insert(const BinType & item)
{
try
{
    Node *before = head;
    Node *after = before->next;

    if (numberOfNodes == 0)
    {
        before->next = tail = CreateNode(item, after);
    }
    else
    {
        Node *tmp = head;

        while (tmp && tmp->next != NULL) tmp = tmp->next;

        Node *tmp1 = CreateNode(item, nullptr);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            head = tmp1;
        else
            tmp->next = tmp1;
    }
    numberOfNodes++;
}
catch (const std::exception err)
{
    cerr << "QueueList Error: " << err.what() << endl;
}
}
```

My first Method

> ```
> BinType QueueList::first() const
> {
>  return head->item;
> }
> ```

My Driver

```
    QueueList one;
    one.insert(2);
    cout<<one.first()<<endl;
```

When I do this the console prints 0.  I am not sure why its not returning 2?

EDIT: class code

```
#include "QueueList.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


namespace DB{


void QueueList::releaseNodes()
{
    Node *del = head;

    while (head != nullptr) {
        head = head->next;

        del->next = nullptr;
        delete del;

        del = head;
    }

    tail = nullptr;
    numberOfNodes = 0;
   }

 QueueList::Node* QueueList::CreateNode(const BinType & item, Node * const        next)
 {

    if (new Node(item,next) == nullptr)
 {
    throw bad_alloc();
 }

  return new Node(item,next);

 }

 QueueList::QueueList()
 {
   head = tail = CreateNode(BinType(), nullptr);
   numberOfNodes = 0;
 }

 QueueList::~QueueList()
 {
 releaseNodes();
 }

 void QueueList::insert(const BinType & item)
{
 try
{
    Node *before = head;
    Node *after = before->next;

    if (numberOfNodes == 0)
    {
        before = tail = CreateNode(item, nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        Node *tmp = head;

        while (tmp && tmp->next) tmp = tmp->next;

        Node *tmp1 = CreateNode(item, nullptr);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            head = tmp1;
        else
            tmp->next = tmp1;
    }
    numberOfNodes++;
   }
   catch (const std::exception err)
   {
    cerr << "QueueList Error: " << err.what() << endl;
    }
   }

   BinType QueueList::remove()
  {
    if (numberOfNodes == 0)
  {
    throw bad_alloc();
  }

  Node *del;
  del = head->next;
  head->next = del->next;
  numberOfNodes--;

  }

 BinType QueueList::first() const
 {
  return head->item;
 }

 int QueueList::size() const
{
return numberOfNodes;
}

bool QueueList::isEmpty() const
{
if (head == nullptr)
{
    return true;
}
 }




}
```

Comment: looks like when number of nodes is 0, you are not setting the head to be the value of 2. instead you are creating a node and inserting it after head with a value of 2.

Comment: I tried changing before->next to just before, still displayed 0.

Comment: could you show the code to your class maybe ? would be helpful

Comment: okay it is up now.

Comment: change before to head inside the if (numberOfNodes == 0) and see if that fixes your example. If so, ill create a good explanation for ya

Comment: yes it did fix it!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you had was you were creating a local variable,`before`, that was a pointer to the head of your linked list. When inserting, you then changed what `before` was pointing to. Keep in mind, this had no affect on what the head of your list was actually pointing to. You simply changed `before` to point to a new node instead of head.

In your project, make sure you're updating the `head` and `tail` properties of your class, not local pointers that may be pointing to `head` and `tail`. Also, in your class constructor,you should have head set to NULL instead of an actual node. Otherwise, isEmpty will not resolve to true upon creation of an empty list.

Since this is a class project, probably best to let you debug other problems I may see so good luck!! Sometime it's helpful to use GDB to step through your code to find out when it does something you didn't intend it to do.